# php shell_exec as another user

Tags: php, shell, permissions, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and when I am using terminal to execute some command does work correctly, but when execute same command using php I got error:

```
Can't read license data (-102)
Permission denied (errno: 13)
```

In terminal I write:

```
/path/to/file$ ./rlmsign file.txt
```

And rlmsign write something inside file.txt. When I use in php shell_exec:

```
$output = shell_exec('/path/to/file ./rlmsign file.txt');
```

I got error above. Also when I echo user I get www-data. I suppose it's problem in permission, but my file.txt has permission read and write for all users, group and other. Can somenone give me some advice?

Comment: Check paths of parent directories for this file. Because you can traverse a directory if and only if you have execute permission on it. You can read more here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory

Comment: look to see who owns the file with ls and change it if needed chown.

Comment: owner is me, I tried to change owner to www-data but without any succes.

Comment: yes, but does apache run as you?

Comment: How to check that? I think apache run as www-data.